# Vertical spacing inconsistencies around equations

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting, vertical-spacing, format

This seems to be a topic of many questions on here already, but no single answer seems satisfying. I am working with the document below and would like the vertical spacing around each equation to be the same. However, as you can see, this differs depending on the type of environment (matrix, equation, cases etc.) Is there any way to set a consistent vertical space that is equal above and below any type of equation in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\leavevmode\singlespace}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\endsinglespace\vskip0.55\baselineskip\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    X & Y & Z \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    W & Q & V
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 
  \end{array}\right] 
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
f(x) = a(1-x)^b
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
      0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
      0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\leavevmode \singlespace}` forces `\abovedisplayshortskip` in all cases, `\abovedisplayskip` will never be used, is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

TeX places stretchable 'glue' around displayed equations. You can take away the 'stretchability' by replacing this with a fixed length. However, the more you do this, the more likely the situation in which TeX cannot find a good place to break pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\abovedisplayskip = 5pt
\abovedisplayshortskip = 5pt
\belowdisplayskip = 5pt
\belowdisplayshortskip = 5pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    X & Y & Z \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    W & Q & V
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6
  \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
f(x) = a(1-x)^b
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
      0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
      0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```